# C++ in VS : Error LNK 2019 Unresolved Symbol Error

Tags: regex, visual-studio

So i'm programming a menu with a login. 
The login stage checks if the user and password match with the one in the database (phpMyAdmin).

I'm having an error with my functions however, and I have no idea why.

This is my main(cpp):

```
// Kassasysteem.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <tchar.h>
#include "KlassenVerzameling.h"


using namespace std; 

int inloggen();
void menu(int userID);


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
UserDAO admin;

#ifdef User_Offline
    admin.Init();
#endif
    UserDAO gebruikers;
    int userID = 0;
    bool doorgaan = true;

    while (doorgaan)
    {
        userID = inloggen();

        cout << "Welkom " << gebruikers.getUser(userID)->getGebr_naam() << "!" << endl << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int inloggen(){
    UserDAO users;

#ifdef User_Offline
        users.Init();
#endif

        string naam, wachtwoord;

        cout << "Gebruikersnaam (leeg om af te sluiten)? ";
        getline(cin, naam);

        if (naam.empty())
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            wachtwoord = hiddenline("Wachtwoord? ");
            cout << "Verificatie gebruiker...";
            User* gebruiker = users.getUserByName(naam);

            if (gebruiker == 0)
            {
                return -2;
            }
            else {
                if (gebruiker->getWachtwoord() == wachtwoord)
                {
                    return gebruiker->getUserID();
                }
                else {
                    return -2;
                }
            }
        }

#ifdef User_Offline
        users.Dispose();
#endif

}
```

The header file where I declared my functions (that i'm using for the password check):

```
#ifndef SPECIALEINVOER_H_INCLUDED
#define SPECIALEINVOER_H_INCLUDED


string hiddenline(string prompt, char masker = '*');
void setXY(int, int);
int wherex();
int wherey();

#endif
```

And the .cpp file where the functions of my password check process is programmed:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "specialeInvoer.h"

HANDLE hCon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

string hiddenline(string prompt, char masker)
{
    string wachtwoord;
    cout << prompt;
    int x = wherex();
    int y = wherey();
    char c = _getch();

    while (c != 13) //13 = ENTER
    {
        if (c == 8) //backspace
        {
            if (!wachtwoord.empty())
            {
                wachtwoord.pop_back();
                setXY(--x, y);
                cout << " ";
                setXY(x, y);
            }
        }
        else {
            wachtwoord.push_back(c);
            cout << masker;
            x++;
        }
        c = _getch();
    }
    cout << endl;
    return wachtwoord;
}
```

I have no syntax errors only these kind of errors: (for the functions whereex, wherey and setXY).

```
Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl wherex(void)" (?wherex@@YAHXZ) referenced in function "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl hiddenline(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,char)" (?hiddenline@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@D@Z)
```

Some help would be great, I have lurked on stackover for quite some time but mostly i see strange answers with not really the answer that helped me.

thx

Comment: Where is the code that implements wherex()?  You need to include that somehow in your project.

Comment: It's not in the code you showed though, and maybe the linker can't see it either.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in a comment:

Your functions `wherex`, `wherey` and `setXY` are not implemented in your code. 
You have implemented `hiddenline`, why not the others?

Also your function `setXY(int, int)` should be `setXY(int a, int b)`?